# Designing iPhone application with Photoshop or any design tools

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

I need to know how to design new (different) user interface for iPhone with Photoshop or like that tools. I have already checked Photoshop design mockups for iPhone over the internet, but i'm sure, i don't need that, these example psd files shows original iPhone design elements.

I'm just looking to how to design new user interface and how to apply to iPhone application from kick-start. Let me give an example; I need to design new tab bar and apply to my small application as well as uiview, uiview background, modal uiview, buttons like that.

Comment: Did you want to skin the existing ui controls?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unless you have a very good reason to replace the standard user interface elements, don't.  Odds are, you will get them wrong and your application will look completely out-of-place on the device.

However, if you do want to test out mockups of your application interface, I recommend looking at [Briefs](http://giveabrief.com/), a new framework for prototyping iPhone applications.  It lets you specify a series of images and how you would like to interact with them, and creates a working application from that.  It's a very impressive framework for iPhone UI designers.

Comment: Thank you Brad, it seems very good, i'll check that as soon as posible. Did you use it before ? i mean inside of your projects.

Comment: It was just unveiled about a week ago, so I haven't had the time to work with it myself.  The presentation I saw on it was pretty impressive, though.

Answer (score 2):

The 'standard user interface controls' in iPhone are built into the system, which is why there are PSD's out there with those elements inside.

If you want to do a custom UI, you can do whatever you want, but you'll need to program the functionality.

For example, lots of productivity apps like 'To Do' and 'Remember The Milk' use the standard UI controls but with some extra colours or bitmaps added.

Games, on the other hand, tend to have totally customised UIs created in OpenGL. If you want this, you can have any UI you want as long as your programmers are comfortable programming for it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're not writing a game, I'd highly recommend you try to stay with the standard controls. Users know what those controls mean and do, this reduces their learning curve for your application and makes them feel more comfortable with your app.

Comment: Absolutely, i agree with you about the standart controls, i mean i tried to say standart controls with custom design.

Answer (score 0):

You design the custom elements you want and save them as PNG files.  Lots of people have custom backgrounds on views, and custom buttons (in fact I would go so far as to say no app should stick with the standard buttons as they are rather blah).

For views and things you simply put a UIImageView in the background of the view.  Buttons have a very handy mechanism where you can set button images for unpressed and pressed (selected) states, even in Interface Builder.

The only thing you mention customizing I would not, is the tab bar - that has a very specific look and specific icon needs (no color).

Comment: Thank you Kendall for your quick answer, actually i need a good tutorial or book for explain these. Any advice ?

Comment: Not really so much around that area - I think at least some of the sample code may show customized buttons.  For the views, you basically add a UIImageView of the same size as the view, and just add an image to it.  One thing to be aware of is that in 3.0 and beyond, you can set a property on a view called "cornerRadius" and your views will then be rounded.

Comment: it was very interesting, i'II try it today :) 
But, i need more detail about the your part of comment.  you said "basically add a UIImageView of the same size as the view", you mean that shall i use UIImageView instead of UIView ?

Answer (score 0):

iPhone and iPad Stencils from [MobileStencil.com](http://Mobilestencil.com).

Also, matching iPhone and iPad Application SketchBooks from Apress.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to look into Mac OS X's Interface Builder that comes with Xcode, the layout is pretty much predefined or at least, composed of predefined elements.
The only thing you can actually "draw" with a powerful tool like Photoshop, are the images you can use within these elements.

The other way around is to use the Application-like-web-browsing capability of Safari within the iOS but you will end up making a web site in the end and that isn't what you want.

If you are looking for documentation about this, apple's developer area is the best place to start (and probably the best place at all) : http://developer.apple.com/