# iPhone UI controls for WinForms

Tags: iphone, winforms, cocoa-touch, controls

Does anybody know where I could find WinForms controls that mimic those on the iPhone? I am interested in doing some iPhone prototyping using Visual Studio and it would be handy if I could make the controls look like the native iPhone controls.

I know that I could just use Interface Builder on a Mac, but I do not want to do this. I just want to play around with various ideas and I will be much faster in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had a look around for windows forms iPhone controls for mocking and positioning items and couldn't find any. However it's quite easy to do yourself with a few screenshots from the iPhone Simulator. Below is what I've done - I'll update with a download link to the project a bit later.

As mentioned Apple probably won't like, nor let you release a product using their UI style. However for mocking there is nothing to stop you doing it in Visual Studio - they still get their $99 and appstore cut.

[image]

I use Visual Studio as I do XIB-less Monotouch development in it, and want to avoid switching back and forth. For XIB-less apps, designing with interface Builder isn't much faster in my view - but that's a Monotouch-centric viewpoint.

Answer (score 5):

[Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups) has some iPhone-like controls, and you get a mock up done faster than in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

As I pointed out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531284/designing-iphone-application-with-photoshop-or-any-design-tools/1533177#1533177), an alternative to doing this in WinForms might be to mock up your interface using the [Briefs](http://giveabrief.com/) framework.  Briefs lets you use images of any kind to represent screens of your application, and assign interaction behaviors to areas of the images.  You can generate a fully functional iPhone application from this for quick testing of your user interface.

There are a number of iPhone UI wireframe elements for [Photoshop](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/?p=447) and [other illustration applications](http://www.graffletopia.com/stencils/413) out there, so it's pretty easy to draw up your prototype interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Since the iPhone's UIKit controls are very likely highly protected by Apple's trademark and copyrights, I wouldn't expect to find alternative implementations. Since any iPhone development will eventually require using Interface Builder, it's worth repeating what *many* others have said: use the right tool for the job. Learn Interface Builder (it won't take long) and quit trying to shoehorn iPhone development into the Windows tooling.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in doing iPhone apps in C#/VB.NET, MonoTouch is the way to go

http://monotouch.net/

To me it is weird to emulate iPhone UI in WinForms as they are two worlds apart.

Answer (score 0):

You can take help of this new tool [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/), which helps you to create the native application by using c#.